# Passing an image from webview to application (IOS and Android)

Tags: android, ios, android-webview, hybrid-mobile-app, wkwebview

I'm building hybrid applications that rely on 2-way communication between javascript in a webview and the hosting application.

Attitudes differ somewhat as in **IOS** the JS can send a message to swift (using `WKWebView`), that listens through

```
userContentController(userContentController: WKUserContentController,
didReceiveScriptMessage message: WKScriptMessage)
```

when implementing the `WKScriptMessageHandler` protocol,

whereas in **Android** the JS can actually call an Android method that has `@JavascriptInterface` annotation, after calling `addJavascriptInterface()`.

Both approaches are OK for me, as I'm passing around data using JSON strings. Question is, what if I need to pass a media file, say an image or video, from the web page to the application? should I just pass a bitmap inside the json? Seems a little naive... recommendations?

edit: when passing an image from the application to the webpage I save the file to the file system and send the filename to the webview. Can it be done the other way around? Can **javascript** save to the hosting mobile device file system?

Answer (score 0):

You have to host(in case of webapp) or store(in case of mobile app) the image and pass the image url, not exactly the image. 
Almost all api that uses images bitmap also takes image url.

regards
Ashish

Comment: Thanks. I use this for passing images from the application to the webpage, not sure if it can be done the other way around - how to save an image from JS to the local device file system? I'll add that to the original question.

Comment: After you have captured the string from json.Its same as normal file write operation, just keep the extension .jpg or .png If you are looking for code.

Answer (score 0):

To answer your second question which is there are comments, use the following code. 
Here the html content is your binary content:

```
FileWriter imageFileWriter = null;
BufferedWriter imageBufferedWriter = null;
ABOUtil.createDir(InMemoryDataStructure.FILE_PATH.getFileDirForimage());
File imageFileDir = new File(InMemoryDataStructure.FILE_PATH.getFileDirForimage());
String imageName = "/finalimage"+ filename + jpg
File mimageFile = new File(imageFileDir, imageName);

try {
    imageFileWriter = new FileWriter(mimageFile, false);
    imageBufferedWriter = new BufferedWriter(imageFileWriter);
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();

    sb.append(htmlContent);
    sb.append(scriptInjectJavascript(lstimageNameValue));
    imageBufferedWriter.write(sb.toString());
    imageBufferedWriter.close();
    return mimageFile;
} 
catch (IOException e) {
    MAFLogger.e("", "", e);
}
finally{
    if(imageFileWriter!=null)
        try {
            imageFileWriter.close();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            MAFLogger.e("","",e);
        }
    if(imageBufferedWriter!=null)
        try {
            imageBufferedWriter.close();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            MAFLogger.e("","",e);
        }
}
```